# running sas filename pipe in unix

Tags: unix, file-io, sas, pipe, sas-macro

I have the following piece of SAS code that I run on Windows and works well. But now I am looking to run it from unix. I guess multiple things could go wrong here -- initially I was figuring out about double quotes in the filepath definition that got resolved. But now I am having issues as to how to make my code run on unix. So, what would be the equivalent Unix command for the filename command line? Should I use ls -al or something? ... My equivalent folder in Unix is

```
/home/personal/bulk file all &date.
```

Note that there is a space in the folder name. Even though Windows seems to handle this, would be it also concern in Unix?

Appreciate your help deeply.

```
Windows
%let filepath = %bquote("C:\Personal\bulk file all &date");
filename CDR_Bulk pipe "dir &filepath /a:-d-h-s /b /s";


data tempsetup;
infile CDR_Bulk;
input ;
schedulefile=_infile_;
if scan(schedulefile,-1,'\') = "test.txt" then delete;
run;
```

Comment: Please don't open up multiple questions with the same problem.

Comment: My question is related to the previous question I had posted, but it is not the same. I think they are two different issues - one is getting the correct double quotes, and this one is figuring out how to get running on to another OS.

Comment: You haven't marked the other one complete yet, and this is effectively the same question.

Comment: I just did. Thank you. Its from the same program I am writing, but the answer to that question is definitely not the answer to this question.